# upload application content on social networking sites

Tags: android, image, audio, social-networking

In my personal diary application i want to upload a content as well as attached images and audio files.
How can do it?

only content will be upload but image file cannot be upload.

i am use the Intent.....Action_Send.

Answer (score 0):

try looking at the [twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs) and in the [Facebook developers](http://developers.facebook.com/) for reference about posting on them.

for the rest of them, searching Google for  API will give you the answer